# What happens if you json_encode return api data that is already JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have not worked with JSON/PHP/AJAX in a while and I am having a hard time accessing the returned data.

I have an AJAX function that calls a PHP script which does an API call that returns JSON  in `$data`. That JSON is decoded via `$newJSON = json_decode($data);` and looped through to create some formatted HTML stored in `$cleanHTML`. I am then placing the  variable `$cleanHTML` and the original `$data` variable into a new array `$processedReturnArray = array($cleanHTML, $data);` and encoding it `echo json_encode($processedReturnArray);`  to pass back to the AJAX script.

**My Question:** I am assuming JSON encoding the array that has a JSON string in it is not the correct way. What is the best solution?

This is my JS you will see where I am `console.log` and the first element `$cleanHTML` I am seeing but when I try to log value from the second object I am getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined`

```
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {    
        $("#searchFormSubmit").click(function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("In First Part of Search Submit!");
            var address = $('#address').val();
        $.ajax({
                url : the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
                type : 'post',
                data : {
                    action : 'travel_app_ajaxdata',
                    thangs : $('#CoreSearchForm').serialize()
                },
                success : function( response ) {
                    returnData = JSON.parse(response);
                     console.log("This is my Clean HTML" + returnData[0]);
                     console.log("This is my Location" + returnData[1]);
                      console.log("TEST DATA - EVENT: " + returnData[1]["resultsPage"]);
                    $('.return_data').html(returnData[0]);
},
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        } 
        });
    });

});
```

The PHP script is made up of multiple Classes and I can post pieces if it will help with the solution. I can also post a sample of the JSON returned.

Comment: if `$data` is an object you might try `$data->cleanhtml=$cleanHTML` and then `json_encode($data)`?

Comment: @RamRaider I will try that right now and follow up with results. Thanks.

Comment: jQuery AJAX functions decode returned data automatically as long as there's any hint about its type. If you then apply `JSON.parse()` you'll be trying to parse an object, not a string (there's no such thing as "JSON object", JSON is a string format). I can't see hints in your client code so your app will stop working if e.g.the server happens to return a correct `Content-Type` header.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you are correct I miss used the word object when talking about the JSON received from the API. If I add `dataType: 'json',` to my Ajax function should I still json_encode that I echo from php to the Ajax function?

Comment: I'm probably not understanding your concerns. If JavaScript expects JSON then PHP must render JSON. I don't know what your PHP code looks like but `json_encode()` is the only builtin function to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in your php code that handles the request set the header to application/json. Like

```
header('Content-Type:application/json');
return json_encode($processedReturnArray);
```

Comment: That was going to be my next question. When I checked the header of the response and it was set to text/html. I updated the header per your recommendation and I am already seeing what I expect. I need to run a few more test just to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps :)